# Combining ASP with SQL Queries, time functions

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic

Hi I neeed to combine SQL with ASP Classic

I want to compare date from the DB with the date of the server...For some reason it dosent work.

This is my code. I can't to activate it.

The error is: Too few arguments are used in the function DATEDIFF(08/05/2014,date)<=1

```
<%
Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};" & _
       "Dbq=" & Server.MapPath("db\web.mdb") & ";"

mySQL = "SELECT * FROM Meetings where DATEDIFF(now(),date)  <=1 " 

Set oRS = oConn.Execute (mySQL)
Response.Write "<ul>"

Do Until oRS.EOF
Response.Write  "<li>" & oRS.Fields("Description") & "</li>"
oRS.MoveNext
Loop
Response.Write "</ul>"

%>
```

Comment: what doesn't work????

Comment: It's tells me that I pass worng number of arguments..

Comment: please post the full error message

Answer (score 3):

You are not passing all the needed arguments to the DATEDIFF function, according to the Microsoft reference this is the syntax:

***DateDiff(interval, date1, date2 [, firstdayofweek] [, firstweekofyear] )***

you are passing `DATEDIFF(now(),date)`, assuming that date is a datetime variable you are not passing the first argument, interval:

The interval argument has these settings:

```
Setting  |Description
---------+--------------
yyyy     |Year
q        |Quarter
m        |Month
y        |Day of year
d        |Day
w        |Weekday
ww       |Week
h        |Hour
n        |Minute
s        |Second
```

The official reference for further information:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/datediff-funcion-HA001228811.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I Think is that what you need:

```
sql="SELECT * FROM Meetings where DATEDIFF(d, now(), date) <= 1"
```

You ask the DATEDIFF but don't tell what data you want to be returned (Day, Minute, Second, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change your SQL to:
mySQL = "SELECT * FROM Meetings where DATEDIFF('d', date(),date)  <=1"

Please note that the difference type d should be within quotes.